# Changing the legend in an sns scatterplot

Tags: python, seaborn, legend, scatter-plot

I'm using seaborn's scatterplot to create the following visualization:

[image]

```
sns.scatterplot(x="page", y="length", hue="% of marginal annotations", size="% of marginal annotations", legend="brief", data=df, palette = cmap, s=40, alpha=.6, sizes=(20, 200)).set(xlabel='Folio number', ylabel='Length')
```

When set to 'brief,' the legend breaks down the data into 40% increments from 0 up to... 120! I'm concerned that this legend is going to mislead the reader into thinking that some of my data points are above 100% (this is never the case). How do I change the legend so that it presents the different sizes from 0 to 100% ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're confident none of your `"% of marginal annotations"` data points exceed 100% then you could simply add `.legend(range(0, 125, 25))`, essentially defining what values should be included in the legend.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="page", y="length", hue="% of marginal annotations",
                     size="% of marginal annotations", legend="brief", data=df,
                     palette = cmap, s=40, alpha=.6, sizes=(20, 200))
ax.set(xlabel='Folio number', ylabel='Length')
ax.legend(range(0, 125, 25))
```

Comment: `.legend(range(0, 125, 25))` provides the desired scale but the legend keys are now in the wrong order. Tere's now a big dot next to 0, nothing at all next to 25, the small dot you would normally find next to 0 is now next to 50, etc.